# Why is the compiler optimizing these cases differently?

Tags: c++, performance, assembly, crc, intrinsics

The snippet of code found below demonstrates a situation in which calling the CRC32 compiler intrinsic on **7 bytes** of data in two different ways (e.g. *case0()* & *case1()*) results in different compiler optimizations. These differences in compiler optimizations produce vastly different execution times (e.g. [Test_Construction, Case: 0, Bytes: 7]).

For reference, I have included logic for calling CRC32 on 6 bytes of data in the same fashion. However, as you can see from the generated output, the resulting execution times do not suffer the same performance hit as experienced when working with 7 bytes of data.

**Generated output of a single pass**
    - 4 unique tests for each data size of interest (6 & 7 bytes):

```
Test_Construction <Case: 0, Bytes: 7>:    139.5543 ms
Test_Construction <Case: 1, Bytes: 7>:     38.6545 ms
Test_Reference    <Case: 0, Bytes: 7>:     26.2616 ms
Test_Reference    <Case: 1, Bytes: 7>:     38.8118 ms
Test_Construction <Case: 0, Bytes: 6>:     26.2925 ms
Test_Construction <Case: 1, Bytes: 6>:     29.5819 ms
Test_Reference    <Case: 0, Bytes: 6>:     25.3754 ms
Test_Reference    <Case: 1, Bytes: 6>:     28.7829 ms
```

**I have two questions:**

> 1. Why is the compiler producing different optimizations
>      (e.g. specifically in the case of [Test_Construction, Case: 0, Bytes: 7]?
>
>    - It looks like when [Test_Construction, Case: 0, Bytes: 7] is translated into machine code it contains additional instructions which move data from the stack into the registers and then back out on the stack. This does not seem to occur in any other scenario. CRC is then called once on data found within a register and once on data on the stack. Why would it do this?
> 2. Why is the performance dropping in the first place?
>
>    - Is it due to the additional stack logic (memory operations) found in [Test_Construction, Case: 0, Bytes: 7] machine code?
>    - Could the order of the operations contribute?
>    - Is there a way to stop the optimizer from producing this suboptimal machine code?

**UPDATE 1 - 4/7/17:**

- @1201ProgramAlarm, johnnycrash

  - I just want to clarify that I would like to optimize/reduce the generated machine code. I purposefully overlapped the 4th byte in [Case: 0, Bytes: 7] in order to call CRC32_u32 twice to avoid having to make the following 3 calls: CRC32_u32 + CRC32_u16 + CRC32_u8.
  - As a follow up to your suggestion, johnnycrash, I attempted to remove the call to memcpy completely in CFunc's constructor, specifically in the case that the data is 7 bytes in size. See code directly below. However, this had no effect on the execution time.

.

```
template<int N>
void MemCpy(char* szDst, const char* szSrc) {
    memcpy(szDst, szSrc, N);
}

// I tried both of these alternatives to memcpy, no luck.
template<> void MemCpy<7>(char* szDst, const char* szSrc) {
    //AS4(szDst) = AS4(szSrc), AS2(szDst+4) = AS2(szSrc+4),  AS1(szDst+6) = AS1(szSrc+6);
    AS4(szDst) = AS4(szSrc), AS4(szDst+3) = AS4(szSrc+3);
}
```

> **Environment Details:**

```
Windows Server 2012 R2 x64
Intel Xeon X5670
```

> **Assembly Reference:**

```
-------------------------------------------------------
Test_Construction <Case: 0, Bytes: 7>:    139.5543 ms
-------------------------------------------------------
00007FF62D7911CC  call        CBench::CBench (07FF62D791000h)  
00007FF62D7911D1  xor         r8d,r8d  
00007FF62D7911D4  lea         r10,[_a (07FF62D794630h)]  
00007FF62D7911DB  mov         r9d,1312D00h  
                for (int iPass = 0; iPass < PASSES; ++iPass) {
                                int i = iPass & (DimensionOf(_a) - 1);
00007FF62D7911E1  mov         rax,r8  
00007FF62D7911E4  inc         r8  
00007FF62D7911E7  and         eax,3FFh  
                                auto& x = (USEREF) ? *(CFunc<N>*)_a[i] : *new(buf) CFunc<N>(_a[i]);
00007FF62D7911EC  lea         rcx,[rax+rax*2]  
00007FF62D7911F0  movzx       eax,word ptr [r10+rcx*8+4]  
00007FF62D7911F6  mov         edx,dword ptr [r10+rcx*8]  
00007FF62D7911FA  mov         word ptr [rsp+44h],ax  
00007FF62D7911FF  movzx       eax,byte ptr [r10+rcx*8+6]  
00007FF62D791205  mov         byte ptr [rsp+46h],al  
                                ii += (CASE == 1) ? x.Case1() : x.Case0();
00007FF62D791209  mov         eax,7  
00007FF62D79120E  crc32       eax,edx  
                                auto& x = (USEREF) ? *(CFunc<N>*)_a[i] : *new(buf) CFunc<N>(_a[i]);
00007FF62D791213  mov         dword ptr [buf],edx  
                                ii += (CASE == 1) ? x.Case1() : x.Case0();
00007FF62D791217  crc32       eax,dword ptr [rsp+43h]  
00007FF62D79121E  add         ebx,eax  
00007FF62D791220  sub         r9,1  
00007FF62D791224  jne         Test_Func<0,7,0>+71h (07FF62D7911E1h)  
                }
                return ii;
00007FF62D791226  lea         rcx,[Bench]  
00007FF62D79122B  call        CBench::~CBench (07FF62D791030h)


-------------------------------------------------------
Test_Construction <Case: 1, Bytes: 7>:     38.6545 ms
-------------------------------------------------------
00007FF62D7912A9  call        CBench::CBench (07FF62D791000h)  
00007FF62D7912AE  xor         r8d,r8d  
00007FF62D7912B1  lea         r10,[_a (07FF62D794630h)]  
00007FF62D7912B8  mov         r9d,1312D00h  
00007FF62D7912BE  xchg        ax,ax  
                for (int iPass = 0; iPass < PASSES; ++iPass) {
                                int i = iPass & (DimensionOf(_a) - 1);
00007FF62D7912C0  mov         rax,r8  
00007FF62D7912C3  inc         r8  
00007FF62D7912C6  and         eax,3FFh  
                                auto& x = (USEREF) ? *(CFunc<N>*)_a[i] : *new(buf) CFunc<N>(_a[i]);
00007FF62D7912CB  lea         rcx,[rax+rax*2]  
                                ii += (CASE == 1) ? x.Case1() : x.Case0();
00007FF62D7912CF  movzx       eax,word ptr [r10+rcx*8+4]  
00007FF62D7912D5  movzx       edx,byte ptr [r10+rcx*8+6]  
00007FF62D7912DB  shl         rdx,10h  
00007FF62D7912DF  or          rdx,rax  
00007FF62D7912E2  mov         eax,dword ptr [r10+rcx*8]  
00007FF62D7912E6  shl         rdx,20h  
00007FF62D7912EA  or          rdx,rax  
00007FF62D7912ED  mov         eax,7  
00007FF62D7912F2  crc32       rax,rdx  
00007FF62D7912F8  add         ebx,eax  
00007FF62D7912FA  sub         r9,1  
00007FF62D7912FE  jne         Test_Func<1,7,0>+70h (07FF62D7912C0h)  
                }
                return ii;
00007FF62D791300  lea         rcx,[Bench]  
00007FF62D791305  call        CBench::~CBench (07FF62D791030h)


-------------------------------------------------------
Test_Reference    <Case: 0, Bytes: 7>:     26.2616 ms
-------------------------------------------------------
00007FF62D791386  call        CBench::CBench (07FF62D791000h)  
00007FF62D79138B  xor         edx,edx  
00007FF62D79138D  lea         r9,[_a (07FF62D794630h)]  
00007FF62D791394  mov         r8d,1312D00h  
00007FF62D79139A  nop         word ptr [rax+rax]  
                for (int iPass = 0; iPass < PASSES; ++iPass) {
                                int i = iPass & (DimensionOf(_a) - 1);
00007FF62D7913A0  mov         rax,rdx  
                                ii += (CASE == 1) ? x.Case1() : x.Case0();
00007FF62D7913A3  mov         ecx,7  
                for (int iPass = 0; iPass < PASSES; ++iPass) {
                                int i = iPass & (DimensionOf(_a) - 1);
00007FF62D7913A8  and         eax,3FFh  
00007FF62D7913AD  inc         rdx  
                                auto& x = (USEREF) ? *(CFunc<N>*)_a[i] : *new(buf) CFunc<N>(_a[i]);
00007FF62D7913B0  lea         rax,[rax+rax*2]  
                                ii += (CASE == 1) ? x.Case1() : x.Case0();
00007FF62D7913B4  crc32       ecx,dword ptr [r9+rax*8]  
00007FF62D7913BB  crc32       ecx,dword ptr [r9+rax*8+3]  
00007FF62D7913C3  add         ebx,ecx  
00007FF62D7913C5  sub         r8,1  
00007FF62D7913C9  jne         Test_Func<0,7,1>+70h (07FF62D7913A0h)  
                }
                return ii;
00007FF62D7913CB  lea         rcx,[Bench]  
00007FF62D7913D0  call        CBench::~CBench (07FF62D791030h)  


-------------------------------------------------------    
Test_Reference    <Case: 1, Bytes: 7>:     38.8118 ms
-------------------------------------------------------
00007FF62D791449  call        CBench::CBench (07FF62D791000h)  
00007FF62D79144E  xor         r8d,r8d  
00007FF62D791451  lea         r10,[_a (07FF62D794630h)]  
00007FF62D791458  mov         r9d,1312D00h  
00007FF62D79145E  xchg        ax,ax  
                for (int iPass = 0; iPass < PASSES; ++iPass) {
                                int i = iPass & (DimensionOf(_a) - 1);
00007FF62D791460  mov         rax,r8  
00007FF62D791463  inc         r8  
00007FF62D791466  and         eax,3FFh  
                                auto& x = (USEREF) ? *(CFunc<N>*)_a[i] : *new(buf) CFunc<N>(_a[i]);
00007FF62D79146B  lea         rax,[rax+rax*2]  
                                ii += (CASE == 1) ? x.Case1() : x.Case0();
00007FF62D79146F  movzx       edx,byte ptr [r10+rax*8+6]  
00007FF62D791475  lea         rcx,[r10+rax*8]  
00007FF62D791479  movzx       eax,word ptr [r10+rax*8+4]  
00007FF62D79147F  shl         rdx,10h  
00007FF62D791483  or          rdx,rax  
00007FF62D791486  mov         eax,dword ptr [rcx]  
00007FF62D791488  shl         rdx,20h  
00007FF62D79148C  or          rdx,rax  
00007FF62D79148F  mov         eax,7  
00007FF62D791494  crc32       rax,rdx  
00007FF62D79149A  add         ebx,eax  
00007FF62D79149C  sub         r9,1  
00007FF62D7914A0  jne         Test_Func<1,7,1>+70h (07FF62D791460h)  
                }
                return ii;
00007FF62D7914A2  lea         rcx,[Bench]  
00007FF62D7914A7  call        CBench::~CBench (07FF62D791030h) 


-------------------------------------------------------
Test_Construction <Case: 0, Bytes: 6>:     26.2925 ms
-------------------------------------------------------
00007FF62D791526  call        CBench::CBench (07FF62D791000h)  
00007FF62D79152B  xor         r8d,r8d  
00007FF62D79152E  lea         r10,[_a (07FF62D794630h)]  
00007FF62D791535  mov         r9d,1312D00h  
00007FF62D79153B  nop         dword ptr [rax+rax]  
                for (int iPass = 0; iPass < PASSES; ++iPass) {
                                int i = iPass & (DimensionOf(_a) - 1);
00007FF62D791540  mov         rax,r8  
00007FF62D791543  inc         r8  
00007FF62D791546  and         eax,3FFh  
                                auto& x = (USEREF) ? *(CFunc<N>*)_a[i] : *new(buf) CFunc<N>(_a[i]);
00007FF62D79154B  lea         rcx,[rax+rax*2]  
                                ii += (CASE == 1) ? x.Case1() : x.Case0();
00007FF62D79154F  mov         eax,6  
00007FF62D791554  crc32       eax,dword ptr [r10+rcx*8]  
                                auto& x = (USEREF) ? *(CFunc<N>*)_a[i] : *new(buf) CFunc<N>(_a[i]);
00007FF62D79155B  movzx       edx,word ptr [r10+rcx*8+4]  
                                ii += (CASE == 1) ? x.Case1() : x.Case0();
00007FF62D791561  crc32       eax,dx  
00007FF62D791567  add         ebx,eax  
00007FF62D791569  sub         r9,1  
00007FF62D79156D  jne         Test_Func<0,6,0>+70h (07FF62D791540h)  
                }
                return ii;
00007FF62D79156F  lea         rcx,[Bench]  
00007FF62D791574  call        CBench::~CBench (07FF62D791030h)


-------------------------------------------------------
Test_Construction <Case: 1, Bytes: 6>:     29.5819 ms
-------------------------------------------------------
00007FF62D7915F9  call        CBench::CBench (07FF62D791000h)  
00007FF62D7915FE  xor         r8d,r8d  
00007FF62D791601  lea         r10,[_a (07FF62D794630h)]  
00007FF62D791608  mov         r9d,1312D00h  
00007FF62D79160E  xchg        ax,ax  
                for (int iPass = 0; iPass < PASSES; ++iPass) {
                                int i = iPass & (DimensionOf(_a) - 1);
00007FF62D791610  mov         rax,r8  
00007FF62D791613  inc         r8  
00007FF62D791616  and         eax,3FFh  
                                auto& x = (USEREF) ? *(CFunc<N>*)_a[i] : *new(buf) CFunc<N>(_a[i]);
00007FF62D79161B  lea         rcx,[rax+rax*2]  
                                ii += (CASE == 1) ? x.Case1() : x.Case0();
00007FF62D79161F  mov         eax,dword ptr [r10+rcx*8]  
00007FF62D791623  movzx       edx,word ptr [r10+rcx*8+4]  
00007FF62D791629  shl         rdx,20h  
00007FF62D79162D  or          rdx,rax  
                                ii += (CASE == 1) ? x.Case1() : x.Case0();
00007FF62D791630  mov         eax,6  
00007FF62D791635  crc32       rax,rdx  
00007FF62D79163B  add         ebx,eax  
00007FF62D79163D  sub         r9,1  
00007FF62D791641  jne         Test_Func<1,6,0>+70h (07FF62D791610h)  
                }
                return ii;
00007FF62D791643  lea         rcx,[Bench]  
00007FF62D791648  call        CBench::~CBench (07FF62D791030h) 


-------------------------------------------------------
Test_Reference    <Case: 0, Bytes: 6>:     25.3754 ms
-------------------------------------------------------
00007FF62D7916C6  call        CBench::CBench (07FF62D791000h)  
00007FF62D7916CB  xor         edx,edx  
00007FF62D7916CD  lea         r9,[_a (07FF62D794630h)]  
00007FF62D7916D4  mov         r8d,1312D00h  
00007FF62D7916DA  nop         word ptr [rax+rax]  
                for (int iPass = 0; iPass < PASSES; ++iPass) {
                                int i = iPass & (DimensionOf(_a) - 1);
00007FF62D7916E0  mov         rax,rdx  
                                ii += (CASE == 1) ? x.Case1() : x.Case0();
00007FF62D7916E3  mov         ecx,6  
                for (int iPass = 0; iPass < PASSES; ++iPass) {
                                int i = iPass & (DimensionOf(_a) - 1);
00007FF62D7916E8  and         eax,3FFh  
00007FF62D7916ED  inc         rdx  
                                auto& x = (USEREF) ? *(CFunc<N>*)_a[i] : *new(buf) CFunc<N>(_a[i]);
00007FF62D7916F0  lea         rax,[rax+rax*2]  
                                ii += (CASE == 1) ? x.Case1() : x.Case0();
00007FF62D7916F4  crc32       ecx,dword ptr [r9+rax*8]  
                                ii += (CASE == 1) ? x.Case1() : x.Case0();
00007FF62D7916FB  crc32       ecx,word ptr [r9+rax*8+4]  
00007FF62D791704  add         ebx,ecx  
00007FF62D791706  sub         r8,1  
00007FF62D79170A  jne         Test_Func<0,6,1>+70h (07FF62D7916E0h)  
                }
                return ii;
00007FF62D79170C  lea         rcx,[Bench]  
00007FF62D791711  call        CBench::~CBench (07FF62D791030h)


-------------------------------------------------------
Test_Reference    <Case: 1, Bytes: 6>:     28.7829 ms
-------------------------------------------------------
00007FF62D791799  call        CBench::CBench (07FF62D791000h)  
00007FF62D79179E  xor         edx,edx  
00007FF62D7917A0  lea         r9,[_a (07FF62D794630h)]  
00007FF62D7917A7  mov         r8d,1312D00h  
00007FF62D7917AD  nop         dword ptr [rax]  
                for (int iPass = 0; iPass < PASSES; ++iPass) {
                                int i = iPass & (DimensionOf(_a) - 1);
00007FF62D7917B0  mov         rax,rdx  
00007FF62D7917B3  inc         rdx  
00007FF62D7917B6  and         eax,3FFh  
                                auto& x = (USEREF) ? *(CFunc<N>*)_a[i] : *new(buf) CFunc<N>(_a[i]);
00007FF62D7917BB  lea         rax,[rax+rax*2]  
                                ii += (CASE == 1) ? x.Case1() : x.Case0();
00007FF62D7917BF  movzx       ecx,word ptr [r9+rax*8+4]  
00007FF62D7917C5  mov         eax,dword ptr [r9+rax*8]  
00007FF62D7917C9  shl         rcx,20h  
00007FF62D7917CD  or          rcx,rax  
00007FF62D7917D0  mov         eax,6  
00007FF62D7917D5  crc32       rax,rcx  
00007FF62D7917DB  add         ebx,eax  
00007FF62D7917DD  sub         r8,1  
00007FF62D7917E1  jne         Test_Func<1,6,1>+70h (07FF62D7917B0h)  
                }
                return ii;
00007FF62D7917E3  lea         rcx,[Bench]  
00007FF62D7917E8  call        CBench::~CBench (07FF62D791030h)
```

> **Source Code:**

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include "new"
#include <cstdio>
#include <intrin.h>

#define DimensionOf(x)      (sizeof(x)/sizeof(*(x)))
#define INL                 __forceinline
#define NOINL               __declspec(noinline)
#define PASSES              20000000
#define AS1(a_)             (*(U1*)(a_))
#define AS2(a_)             (*(U2*)(a_))
#define AS3(a_)             ((U4(AS1((char*)(a_) + 2))<<16) | AS2(a_))
#define AS4(a_)             (*(U4*)(a_))
#define AS6(a_)             ((U8(AS2((char*)(a_) + 4))<<32) | AS4(a_))
#define AS7(a_)             ((U8(AS3((char*)(a_) + 4))<<32) | AS4(a_))

typedef unsigned char       U1;
typedef unsigned short      U2;
typedef unsigned int        U4;
typedef unsigned long long  U8;

typedef char TData[24];
TData _a[0x400];

// CBench is for benchmarking code
class CBench {
    __int64     m_nStart;
    const char* m_desc;
public:
    // No inline declared 
    // Reasoning:   Simplifies the assembly code. 
    //              Easier to see how the optimizer optimizes different variations of an algorithm.
    NOINL CBench(const char *szDesc) 
        : m_desc(szDesc), m_nStart(GetBenchMark()) { }

    NOINL ~CBench() {
        __int64 cpuFreq, deltaTime(GetBenchMark() - m_nStart);
        QueryPerformanceFrequency((LARGE_INTEGER*) &cpuFreq);
        double execTimeInMS = ((double) deltaTime * 1000) / cpuFreq;
        printf("%s:\t%10.4f ms\n", m_desc, execTimeInMS);
    }

    NOINL static __int64 GetBenchMark(void) {
        __int64 nBenchMark;
        QueryPerformanceCounter((LARGE_INTEGER*) &nBenchMark);
        return nBenchMark;
    }
};

// CFunc executes CRC32 intrinsics on 6 & 7 bytes in two different ways
template <int N>
struct CFunc {
    char m_ach[N];
    INL CFunc(const char* sz) {
        memcpy(m_ach, sz, N);
    }
    INL U4 Case0() {
        return (N == 7) ? _mm_crc32_u32(_mm_crc32_u32(N, AS4(m_ach)), AS4(m_ach + 3))
                        : _mm_crc32_u16(_mm_crc32_u32(N, AS4(m_ach)), AS2(m_ach + 4));
    }
    INL U4 Case1() {
        return (N == 7) ? (U4) _mm_crc32_u64(N, AS7(m_ach))
                        : (U4) _mm_crc32_u64(N, AS6(m_ach));
    }

};

// Evaluates performance dependent on:
//  -   CASE    :   CRC procedure
//  -   N       :   Number of bytes
//  -   USEREF  :   True,   reference to pre-existing CFunc object
//                  False,  constructing new CFunc object
template<U4 CASE, int N, bool USEREF>
NOINL int Test_Func(int ii) {
    char szDesc[64], buf[64];
    (USEREF) ? sprintf(szDesc, "%-18s<Case: %d, Bytes: %d>", "Test_Reference", CASE, N) 
             : sprintf(szDesc, "%-18s<Case: %d, Bytes: %d>", "Test_Construction", CASE, N);
    CBench Bench(szDesc);
    for (int iPass = 0; iPass < PASSES; ++iPass) {
        int i = iPass & (DimensionOf(_a) - 1);
        auto& x = (USEREF) ? *(CFunc<N>*)_a[i] : *new(buf) CFunc<N>(_a[i]);
        ii += (CASE == 1) ? x.Case1() : x.Case0();
    }
    return ii;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        printf("\n>>>>\tPass %d:\n", i);
        // Execute CRC on 7 bytes
        // Construct CFunc Object
        argc = Test_Func<0, 7, false>(argc);
        argc = Test_Func<1, 7, false>(argc);
        // Reference pre-existing CFunc Object
        argc = Test_Func<0, 7, true>(argc);
        argc = Test_Func<1, 7, true>(argc);

        // Execute CRC on 6 bytes
        // Construct CFunc Object
        argc = Test_Func<0, 6, false>(argc);
        argc = Test_Func<1, 6, false>(argc);
        // Reference pre-existing CFunc Object
        argc = Test_Func<0, 6, true>(argc);
        argc = Test_Func<1, 6, true>(argc);
    }
    printf("\n\nDone\n");
    return argc;
}
```

Comment: I haven't spent much time perusing your code, but are you basically asking "why does different code produce different assembly?"?

Comment: That is my question of interest, however, I would like to know why the optimizer is optimizing the code differently when the code is executing very similar logic (see [Test_Construction, Case: 0, Bytes: 6] versus [Test_Construction, Case: 0, Bytes: 7]) and why this does not occur in the scenario of [Test_Construction, Case: 1, Bytes: 7].

Comment: Your Case0, N==7 code includes one byte of the 7 twice when calculating the CRC, which is why it is writing those bytes out to memory.

Comment: @Oliver:  OP is asking more "how can i keep the optimizer from producing this suboptimal code".

Comment: @1201: OP is saying it looks like the optimizer gets confused and decides to write to the stack with case 7, even though it could have used registers.  OP is asking for confirmation that writing back to the stack produces the vastly slower response.

Comment: @johnnycrash Optimizer is not confused.  `a_[3]` gets read from twice in the Case0, N==7 code, and is writing to memory to read those 4 values.  the 4 values starting with `a_[0]` are read from a register.  Those memory writes will slow things down.  Address this fundamental problem (which will return a different CRC than Case1, N==7) may address the performance.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm: I'm guessing the overlap was intentional to use 2 crc32 calls instead of 3.  Maybe the OP can clear it up.  I think the question is the optimizer chose in Test_Construction <Case: 0, Bytes: 7> to write back to memory but used registers in Test_Reference <Case: 0, Bytes: 7>.  In both cases the data passed to crc32 is "overlapped".  In the 6 char example, even when copying to the temp stack obj, the optimizer never wrote to the stack.  It didn't do that for the 7 char.  Hmmm I wonder if the memcpy optimization is involved.  What if OP didnt use memcpy to copy the 7 chars?

Comment: `AS4(m_ach+3)` doesn't even look legal to me.  The alignment requirements of a `U4*` are higher than that of a `char *`.  Casting the pointer from a type with lower alignment to one with higher alignment isn't legal.  On many architectures you'll get a bus error or at least cause an OS trap that will need to handle the unaligned access.  Try using an aligned 32-bit read and shifting to get 3 bytes.

Comment: @TrentP.  On intel, unaligned ops are almost as fast as aligned.  Run this test code with TData[23] instead of TData[24] to see.  Also Test_Reference <0,7>: 26.2616 ms is calling crc32 unaligned and beating the aligned case, Test_Reference <1, 7>: 38.8118 ms, by a large margin.  OP Might add another case doing the aligned crc32 using 3 calls to crc32 (8,16,32) to see how that compares to 1 aligned and one unaligned call to crc32(32).

Comment: The CRC is using `CFunc::m_ach[]`, isn't it?  So the alignment of `TData _a` isn't necessarily what matters in the test that uses placement new to put the CFunc in an aligned buffer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The operations the compiler uses to copy the data into the 7 byte buffer populate registers differently than the crc32 call(s) require(s).  The compiler has to go to the stack to get the registers needed for the crc32 call.  There is no combination of 1,2,4 byte reads and writes that doesn't require a full write to the stack.  When I copied the 7 bytes to an **8 byte buffer**, duplicating the middle byte with a second unaligned 4 byte mov, the compiler saw 2 registers already populated for the crc32 calls and eliminated the stack read/write.

**125.997 ms:**
Use memcpy, which does aligned copying, and unaligned crc32:

```
memcpy(buf, _a[i], 7);
ii += _mm_crc32_u32(_mm_crc32_u32(0, AS4(buf)), AS4(buf + 3));
    movzx       eax,word ptr [_a[i]+4]  
    mov         edx,dword ptr [_a[i]]  
    mov         word ptr [buf+4],ax  
    movzx       eax,byte ptr [_a[i]+6]  
    mov         byte ptr [buf+6],al  
    xor         eax,eax  
    crc32       eax,edx  
    mov         dword ptr [buf],edx  
    crc32       eax,dword ptr [buf+3]
```

The first call to crc32 can use the register edx from the copy, but the second call has no register ready.  It needs the result of the DWORD, WORD, and BYTE movs into buf.  On top of this I suspect the compiler sees a bunch of aliasing going on here and gets conservative.  The compiler has no choice but to build buf on the stack and then access it.

**137.044 ms:** 
memcpy<7>, unaligned overlapped copy into 7 char buf, suffers from the same problem.  The registers involved in the copy step are not the registers needed for the crc32 step.  It has a bit more unaligned access, so it slows down a bit:

```
AS4(buf) = AS4(_a[i]), AS4(buf + 3) = AS4(_a[i] + 3);
ii += _mm_crc32_u32(_mm_crc32_u32(0, AS4(buf)), AS4(buf + 3));
    mov         eax,dword ptr [_a[i]]  
    mov         ecx,dword ptr [_a[i]+3]  
    mov         dword ptr [buf],eax  
    xor         eax,eax  
    mov         dword ptr [buf+3],ecx  
    crc32       eax,dword ptr [buf]  
    crc32       eax,ecx
```

**16.733 ms:**
unaligned overlapped access to source but not overlapped into an 8 byte dest buf, sees a massive improvement!  In this case, we copy the middle byte twice, but we never alias the DWORDS in buf.  If _a[i] = "1234567", then buf would be "12344567":

```
AS4(buf) = AS4(_a[i]), AS4(buf + 4) = AS4(_a[i] + 3);
ii += _mm_crc32_u32(_mm_crc32_u32(0, AS4(buf)), AS4(buf + 4));
    xor         eax,eax  
    crc32       eax,dword ptr [_a[i]]  
    crc32       eax,dword ptr [_a[i]+3]
```

The call to copy first DWORD into buf and the call to copy the second DWORD into buf + 4 use 2 separate registers, which can passed to crc32 directly, so no need to use buf.  The optimizer on a subsequent pass notices the unused data moved to the stack and removes the related operations.

**121.500 ms:**
I then tried the 64 bit crc on the 8 char buf built the same way as above and lost big.  The compiler is not using a single 8 byte register to do the move to buf.

```
AS4(buf) = AS4(_a[i]), AS4(buf + 4) = AS4(_a[i] + 3);
ii += _mm_crc32_u64(0, AS8(buf));
    mov         eax,dword ptr [_a[i]]  
    mov         dword ptr [buf],eax  
    mov         eax,dword ptr [_a[i]+3]  
    mov         dword ptr [buf+3],eax  
    xor         eax,eax  
    crc32       rax,qword ptr [buf]
```

**20.799 ms:**
I changed the move to buf to be 8 bytes instead of 2 x 4 bytes.  This stopped using the stack, but still underperformed the 3rd method above:

```
AS8(buf) = AS4(_a[i]) | ((U8)AS4(_a[i] + 3) << 32);
ii += _mm_crc32_u64(0, AS8(buf));
    mov         ecx,dword ptr [_a[i]+3]  
    mov         eax,dword ptr [_a[i]]  
    shl         rcx,20h  
    or          rcx,rax  
    xor         eax,eax  
    crc32       rax,rcx
```

1 took:  125.997 ms
2 took:  137.044 ms
3 took:   16.733 ms
4 took:  121.500 ms
5 took:   20.799 ms